# Easy way to show that $ \int_{[0,1]}\frac{n}{(1+\sqrt{nx})^2} ~ d\mu$ is unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I wish to show that,

$$ \int_{[0,1]}\frac{n}{(1+\sqrt{nx})^2} ~ d\mu,$$
diverges to infinity as $n \rightarrow \infty$. However, I'm having a hard time showing that this is true, I tried to use the inequality $1+x \le e^{x}$, but that did not work. Is there anyway to show that this is true easily? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried the substitution $u = \sqrt{nx}$?  (Also, [real-analysis] would be a more appropriate tag than [functional-analysis].)

Comment: @PeterMorfe The context of the question is $l^p$ spaces, so I was wondering if there was a way to do it without appealing to substitution? I don't want to invoke u-sub in this context, if possible,

Comment: It's funny because I remember grading for a grad analysis course where something like this appeared as a problem and being amazed because it's arguably calculus.  My point is it may be a trick question.  From where I am sitting, this is a very nice example of a scaling limit --- things become clearer when you "zoom out" (hence set $u = \sqrt{n x}$).  (Assuming $\mu$ is Lebesgue measure...)

Comment: @PeterMorfe Ok, I will try that. I just didn’t  want to use too many "techniques".

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends on what the measure $\mu$ is. Define
$I_n(\mu)=\int_{[0,1]}\frac{n}{(1+\sqrt{nx})^2}\,\mu(dx)$.

- If $\mu=\delta_1$, then
  $$I_n(\delta_1):=\int_{[[0,1]}\frac{n}{(1+\sqrt{nx})^2}\mu(dx)=\frac{n}{(1+\sqrt{n})^2}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}1$$
  and so, $I_n(\delta_1)$ is bounded.
- On the other hand, if $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ in $[0,1]$,
  $$I_n(\lambda)\stackrel{u=nx}{=}\int^n_0\frac{du}{(1+\sqrt{u})^2}\geq\frac14 \int^n_1\frac{du}{u}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\infty$$

Comment: It is $\mu$, the Lebesgue measure. Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason to post these computations rather than letting the OP work through them?

Comment: @PeterMorfe: and what exactly is your objection?